# How to INTENTIONALLY produce a SegFault when testing?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, segmentation-fault, g++, undefined-behavior

I have a piece of Segment Fault catching codes, it processes `SIGSEGV` signal from OS, to prevent my app from crashing, at least get a chance to write some logs before exiting.

In order to test this mechanism, I also wrote a unit test for it with Google Test framework. When I was using g++-9/g++-10, everything work fine. Now I upgraded to g++-12, and the testing code that producing SegFault doesn't work, i.e. it does **NOT** produce any SegFault at all, so I can't use it to do my unit-test.

I guess that because g++-11 or g++-12 enrolled some new protection, to avoid to make codes with UB. But in my case, I do need such codes that results intentionally Segment Fault!

This is my original SegFault producing codes:

```
void doSegFault() {
    int* pi = nullptr;
    std::cout << pi[0] << std::endl;
};
```

### Update

The solution offered by user12002570:

```
#include <signal.h>
raise( SIGEV_SIGNAL );
```

Thanks to user12002570!

Comment: *Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.*

Comment: That is, there is no guarantee that there will be a segfault.

Comment: See [C++ Creating a SIGSEGV for debug purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457928/c-creating-a-sigsegv-for-debug-purposes) and [Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032551/why-is-the-phrase-undefined-behavior-means-the-compiler-can-do-anything-it-wan)

Comment: If you want defined behavior that segfaults, put a giant (>8MB for Linux) array on the stack.

Comment: Examine the generated assembly.  The optimiser is allow to assume you would never execute UB code and could remove all the code in `doSegFault`, or remove any calls to it.  You might have to trick the compiler by using something like `extern int* pi;` so it can't fully statically analyse the function.

Comment: @user12002570 I have resolved it with your tips. Thanks!!!

Comment: UB comments aside, gcc is a bit weird, in that it detects the `nullptr` and sets `bad_bit` on the stream :(

Comment: @Leon it would be helpful to know which tip you're mentioning in your last comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I updated the main post.

Comment: @Leon You're welcome :)